# Sound Frequency to Octave and Key Number

Tags: math, clojure, signal-processing

Given the Frequency of a wave, determine the octave from 0 to 7 and the key number, where 0 is C, 6 is B, C# is 7 and A# is 11.

You could solve it with a series of if statements, but there has to be a better way to do it. The language my project uses is Clojure, but I my guess is that any solution can easily be ported to any language.

Comment: doesn't `cond` work for this case ?

Comment: Yes, but that would be same as the series of ifs. I vaguely remember having seen a solution that used Math/log, but don't know where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following assumes you are using a tempered [chromatic scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_scale). Musical notes have a logarithmic scale of frequency. Every octave up multiplies frequencies by two. Within an octave, there are twelve equal proportional steps for notes C, C#, D, D#, E, F, F#, G, G#, A, A#, B, which are numbered from zero to eleven.

To get the octave number and the note number from the frequency:

- Take the log of the frequency to base 2.
- Subtract the log of the frequency of middle C.

  - The whole number part is the octave number;
  - the (positive) remainder, multiplied by twelve,
    is the note number. This will not be exact.

Notes below middle C have a negative octave number.